# Can we Ignore particular @tag using specflow

Tags: specflow, gherkin

I am using specflow for writing my feature files .my feature files contains "@Tags"(like:@Authentication,@Login,@Permission,etc...) so i want to run all of them except **@Authentication**..

---

so can we use tag like:
 **~@Authentication**  so this will execute all test cases except test case containing  @Authentication tag

Comment: it might help if you explained how you are running your specflow tests and which unit testing framework you are using to test with (Nunit, MSTest etc). Usually specflow translates the @Tags into test categories, so any runner which can run all tests not in a category should be able to do what you want.

Comment: for example if you use the NUnit runner you can specify an /exclude flag to exclude a particular category. See [here](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.3) for more details. without knowing which runner you are using its difficult to give a definite answer

Comment: Sam , I am using "MS Test"

Comment: And how are you running the tests? With the default visual studio runner?

Comment: Yes..using Command line: "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:"Project.dll" /category:"Tags"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated that you are running the tests from the command line using MSTest.exe then you should be able to run tests that are not in a category (according to the [command line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx#category) like this:

> "%VS100COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:"Project.dll" /category:"!Authentication"

Comment: @AdityaK no problem, glad I could help. If this answers your problem please let others know by marking it as correct by clicking the 'tick' on the left of the question, under the numbers. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more details.